# UTPLSQL - работа с курсором, который содержит вложенную таблицу

Tags: юнит-тесты, plsql

Процедура в базе возвращает sys_refcursor, который в свою очередь содержит массив данных (вложенную таблицу). 
Возможно ли как-то средствами utPLSQL проверить корректность возвращаемых данных?

Comment: Добрый день. Чтобы проверить содержимое курсора необходимо его выбрать- курсор это не сам массив, а ссылка на него. Под корректностью, что подразумевается? соответствие типу? что нужно на корректность проверять?

Comment: Доброго дня, 
Курсор я получаю от тестируемой процедуры, то есть по факту - мне нужно написать юнит-тест на процедуру. Далее мне нужно проверить корректность данных, структуру и корректность типов данных, их соответствие чему-либо заданному, да. Так как указанный курсор потом принимается java-приложением, и может возникнуть ошибка при несоответствии типа данных, при некорректном названии столбцов в курсоре, ну и проверка данных уже чисто функциональный тест.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно, это должно выглядеть так. Лучше выделите в отдельную процедуру каждую проверку, а не как у меня

```
   create or replace package test_cur
   as
          procedure unit_test(var1 number,...);
   end;
   /
   create or replace package body test_cur
   as
          procedure unit_test(var1 number,...) is
   begin
          ut.expect( test( var1,... ) ).to_equal(0);
   end;
   end;
   /
   create or replace function test(var1 number,var2 number,...) return number is
   -------------------------------------
   cursor l_cur --для примера взят курсор, можно насоздавать переменных или
                -- использовать готовые типы
   select col1, col2,...--выбираем необходимые столбцы, которые должны быть в 
    --sys_refcursor 
   from table_name
   where rownum =1;
   l_retval l_cur%rowtype;
   -------------------------------------
   l_scur sys_refcursor;
   ---
   l_err exception;
   begin
        proc1(l_scur);--вызываем необходимую процедуру и получаем курсор
        --проверяем структуру и типы данных
        open l_scur;--нужно протащить данные
        fetch l_scur into l_retval;--при несоответствия типов будет вызвано 
                                   --исключение rowtype_mismatch 
        close l_scur;
        -----------------------------------
        --А дальше можно проверять на соответствие значений и 
        --генерировать исключения самому к примеру
        if l_retval.col1 = var2 then
             null;
        else 
             raise l_err;
        end if;
        return 0;--в случае успешного прохождения возвращаем 0
        exception 
              when rowtype_mismatch then 
                   return -1;
              when l_err then
                   return -3;
              when others then
                   return -2;
       end;
       /
```

Надеюсь суть понятна.

Comment: Артём, спасибо за решение, буду работать с ним!

Comment: @Илья, тогда отметьте ответ, как решение.